# Generic Enum param in abstract method

Tags: java, enums

I'm trying to make an abstract Object Factory and I tryied a few things and none of them worked.

What I would like to have is something like this that could be overrided:

```
public abstract ObjectFactory<Obj extends GameObject> {

    public abstract <Type extends Enum> Obj createObject (Type t) ;

}
```

that I could extends ObjectFactory and have:

```
public AntFactory extends ObjectFactory<Ant> {

     @Override
     public Ant createObject(AntType t) { }
}
```

but everything I tryied did not override the createObject method. The only thing that worked for me was:

```
public abstract ObjectFactory<Obj extends GameObject, Type extends Enum> {

    public abstract Obj createObject (Type t) ;

}
```

Theres something that I'm not understanding about this concept or it doesn't work for enum.

Is there a way to keep the extends of enum only in the method and still override it?

Comment: `<Type extends Enum<Type>>`.

Comment: You could have your enums all implement a common interface and parametrize your generic method with that.

Comment: @AndyTurner Still saying that I need to override the abstract method:

    public abstract <T extends Enum<T>> O createObject ( T type) ;


and the method on the extended object:

     public Ant createObject(AntType type)

Comment: @MVAmorim didn't say that would fix it; that's just how you correctly constraint the generic parameter.

Comment: @Andy Turner I see, but the last one works that only extends enum (as all enum extends enum)

Comment: @MVAmorim you actually don't need the generic parameter in the abstract class. `public abstract Obj createObject(Enum<?> t)` is equivalent. Then you override it with `public Ant createObject(Enum<?> t)`. Does this give a hint as to why your current approach doesn't work?

Comment: @AndyTurner I know that it would work, but I need to keep the Enum<?>, and any kind of enum could be passed to the method, I dont want that.
As I can see, theres no way to do this simple in java.
Or I keep the last one i did

Comment: @MVAmorim then you have to have the type variable on the class, not the method, as in your last example.

Comment: @Andy Turner Yeah, that what I did last. I see no problem in that, just wanted to know if theres a simple way of keeping it in the method, but there is not. Thanks for your replies.